# what's the most efficient emacs workflow for compilation and interactive execution cycles (C++/makefile)

Tags: c++, emacs, compilation, makefile

What's the preferred practice for a compile-run cycle in emacs?

Previously, I used <kbd>M-x compile</kbd> (mapped to <kbd>F12</kbd>) with make as my compile command. Within the Makefile I had an entry which would run the program that was compiled. This worked fine when my programs were non-interactive, but the compilation buffer is non-interactive.

Of course I could open a shell and run the executable, but I'd like to automate the compile-run cycle as much as possible and I assume there must be a standard practice for this and I'm guessing my executing-from-the-makefile method is a kluge...

<kbd>C-u F12</kbd> works, but I'm wondering if that's the best approach for doing this (and if so, how can I bind <kbd>F12</kbd> to be equivalent to <kbd>C-u M-x compile</kbd> instead of just <kbd>M-x compile</kbd>?).

Comment: you might get a better response at programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I imagine this will be closed as there are many ways of working, there are no standard answers to the question.

Comment: there are many ways but for something as basic as a compile/run cycle, there must be a preferred practice. If nothing else, it would be useful to learn how to use my current approach and bind c-u alt-x compile to a keyboard shortcut...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't get simpler than <kbd>C-u M-x compile</kbd>.  You already have the Makefile task defined.  So you're just asking how to map this to f12?

Try this:

```lisp
(defun compile-interactive ()
  (interactive)
  (setq current-prefix-arg '(4))
  (call-interactively 'compile))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'compile-interactive)
```

You should also read the [Interactive Options](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/Interactive-Options.html) and [Optional Arguments](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/Optional-Arguments.html) sections of the manual.